# In React, why the input can be kept

Tags: reactjs

In React, when I have a input and user types something, I will call `setState` to save it. We know that when state is changed, the component would be re-rendered.

My question is in this case, why re-render would not reset the input? In my understanding, if we want to keep the input, we should use

```
<input type="text" value={ this.state.input } onChange={(e) => this.handle(e) }
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66hancjk/)

---

Created another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bl084501/4xr6xrqn/). Now when user input anything, the className would be changed, so definitely dom tree is changed. but still the input is not reset after each re-rendering

Comment: Because every time you set state you save the input and then rerender the input, with the saved input value set to the value?

Comment: you set the value of input as `state.input`, so after render the input value is what you type, and why the input is still focus, it is because react just update the difference of `dom tree`, but `input dom` doesn't have any change.

Comment: @chenkehxx, no, in my jsfiddle, I did not explicitly set value of input

Comment: @AndrewLi if you can spend one min looking at my jsfiddle?

Comment: @lynn.fang in `onChange` function, you call setState, it will trigger one render, but you don't set the value of input, it means there is no difference between the ` first dom tree` and` second dom tree` . it means that there is no change in `dom tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the difference between a controlled and an uncontrolled input.  The input HTML element is inherently stateful, with or without React i.e. it will maintain the value of whatever is typed into it.  This is why if we render:

```
<input type='text' />
```

Then whatever is typed will be seen in the input, with no help from React.  This is an uncontrolled component, meaning that the value of the input is not controlled by React.

If we set a value prop on the input:

```
<input type='text' value='' />
```

Then the inherent state of the input is overridden by the value prop.  In the above example it is an unchanging empty string, so no entered characters will ever appear in the input.

So if we take the code from your first fiddle:

```
<input type="text" onChange={ (e) => this.handle(e) } />
```

There is no value prop set, so the value shown within the input comes from the HTML elements inherent statefulness, not from React.  When the component re-renders, the new state and props are irrelevant to the value displayed within the input - again, because this value comes from the state of the HTML element, not from React.